# import tensorflow in Flask caused it hang

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

After following this tutorial [link](https://www.codementor.io/@jqn/deploy-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2-13hp1ilqy2), and having `flaskapp.py` below

```
from flask import Flask
import tensorflow
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  return 'Hello from Flask'
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

1. Without `import tensorflow` line, the Flask app would return `Hello from Flask` - expected behaviour.
2. As soon as I added `import tensorflow`, and restart apache, the browser would hang (I don't see any log in Apache `error.log` file).

Btw, I have installed tensorflow using `sudo pip3 install tensorflow`. If I replaced `tensorflow` with another library like `pandas` it works well.

Something specific with `tensorflow` kills the Flask app.

Below is the result if I run directly using `python3` command

```
python3 flaskapp.py 
2021-01-07 18:58:22.352532: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-01-07 18:58:22.352579: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
 * Serving Flask app "flaskapp" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Kindly suggest, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The logs seem to suggest it works

Comment: Yes, it looks ok if we run with `python3 flaskapp.py`. But it simply hang, when tested from browser (even though it works in browser too when I remove `import tensorflow`

Comment: Try adding tensorflow-related codes in another file, wrap it in a function. Import the function in app.py

Comment: I created `util.py` with a function to display the `tensorflow` version - having `import tensorflow` in it. And modify `flaskapp.py` by adding `import util` -- then the browser hang. Similar behaviour like the original issue.